# Azure B2C Custom Policy - from email decide claims exchange

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I want the below flow for authentication with the Azure B2C custom policy

1. user should see field, where user enters his email id
2. based on the email id (domain name), we decide the claims exchange to authenticate the user with.
3. available claims provider - local account, sign in with Azure B2B AD Tenant.

For point 2, we can parse the domain using [Parse Domain Claims Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#parsedomain).

For point 3, I have already setup the necessary Claims Provider and verified it works, using the default Signing with Local and Social starter pack.

Comment: This sample might help: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery. Also this article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/advanced-home-realm-discovery-in-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/482788. The key word is "home realm discovery".

Comment: @juunas The links were very helpful in understanding the HRD (Home Realm Discovery). The solution shows the usage of SAML and ADFS, and I need to connect with OpenID Connect. So the solution didn't help much.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a user journey such as this.

```xml
<OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-HRD" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-HRD" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
        <Value>domainName</Value>
        <Value>contoso.com</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="AAD-OIDC" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-OIDC" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
    <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>domainName</Value>
        <Value>contoso.com</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  ...
</OrchestrationSteps>
```

The first orchestration steps executes the **SelfAsserted-HRD** technical profile, at which an e-mail address can be entered, and then invokes the **SetDomainName** claims transformation that parses the e-mail domain.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self-Asserted</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-HRD">
      <DisplayName>Self-Asserted HRD</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetDomainName" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

If the e-mail domain is equal to the federated domain, then the second orchestration step executes the **AAD-OIDC** technical profile that redirects the external identity provider.

If the e-mail domain is not equal to the federated domain, then the third orchestration step executes the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** technical profile that shows the local account sign-up or sign-in page.